# Two Random USB Ports on 16-Port USB Hub Disconnects Attached USB Hard Drives

Tags: usb, hard-drive, suspend, usb-drive, disconnect

Two random USB hard drives connected to a Ubuntu 20.04 system via a [16-port USB 3.0 hub](https://smile.amazon.com/Sabrent-Aluminum-Switches-Included-HB-PU16/dp/B07KHRLSTT/) will disconnect on its own after some time. There are 16 USB hard drives attached to this USB hub. The disconnected devices must be power cycled in other for Ubuntu to detect them again via `lsblk`. Simply reconnecting the USB cables of these disconnected devices will not work.

After power cycling the disconnected USB drives, the same 2 drives will disconnect again shortly after. If the USB hub is power cycled, *sometimes* a different set of 2 drives will disconnect.

The system is already configured to disable USB autosuspend by editing GRUB by having this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

Autosuspend also appears to be successfully disabled.

```
$ cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
-1
```

Are there other settings to try to prevent these random USB device disconnects?

Comment: The controller on the hard drive is likley getting a fatal error from which it can not recover.  This could be related to having so many usb drives on the same hub (like an unexpected timeout), or it could be the drive itself is failing or it could be a bug in the drive's firmware triggerd by having so many usb drives on the same hub.

Comment: There might be a useful error in the system logs that could give a clue to the problem.  Also try checking the drive's error logs with smartctl or nvme error-log (apt install nvme-cli) as appropriate.